How to move message from user-system-mailbox to personal-mailbox using mutt
Is there a way to configure mutt to have the same behaviour as the mail command (from mailutils package), i.e. move messages from user-system-mailbox (e.g. /var/mail/root) to personal-mailbox (e.g. /root/mbox or /root/Mail) after reading ?
The current behaviour (after a fresh mutt installation on Ubuntu 23.10 without any tuning) is that messages stay in the index after reading.

Mutt will move read messages to the mailbox specified by the mbox option (by default ~/mbox) if move is set to yes or ask-yes (default is no).
So, for example, using the default value of mbox (save read messages in ~/mbox), getting Mutt to ask whether to save read messages would mean adding the following to your Mutt configuration:
set move = ask-yes


That's what I was looking for, thanks a lot.
